# How to restore variables of a particular scope from a saved checkpoint in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.Saver() 
saver.restore(...)
```

But saver.restore only has options to restore the entire graph. I would like to restore only those variables that are in a specific scope.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have Google's model of InceptionNet in scope `InceptionV1` and you want to load it except for the last layer in scope `InceptionRetrained` you want to retrain.

Assuming you already started retraining the last layer and you created *last_layer.ckpt* file by `saver2.save(session, 'last_layer.ckpt')`, here is how to restore the net from both checkpoints.

```
saver1 = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='InceptionV1'))
saver1.restore(session, 'inception_model_from_google.ckpt')

saver2 = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='InceptionRetrained'))
saver2.restore(session, 'last_layer.ckpt')
```

---

If you are retraining only the last layer, don't forget to disable propagation of the gradient up the network (saves time) by calling the optimizer with `var_list` argument.

```
tf.train.Optimizer(0.0001).minimize(
            loss, var_list=tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='Inceptionretrained'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work and each saver restores variables from all scopes

Comment: I doubt that, I'm sure it works. Can you specify your problem and maybe include some code?

Comment: ```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    v1 =  tf.get_variable("v1", [5, 5, 3])
    v2 =  tf.get_variable("v2", [5, 5, 3])
    saver = tf.train.Saver([v2])
    initializer2 = tf.variables_initializer([v2])
    sess.run(initializer2)
    saver.save(sess, '/path/to/tf_model')
```

Comment: (restarting the kernel)
```
sess = tf.Session()
checkpoint = '/path/to/tf_model.meta'
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint)
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(checkpoint)))

with sess.as_default():
    loaded_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
loaded_vars
```

Comment: outputs
```
[<tf.Variable 'v1:0' shape=(5, 5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'v2:0' shape=(5, 5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Comment: sorry, the comment format doesn't support multi-line code

Comment: And what is your problem? I guess that running session.run(v1) will throw an exception that v1 is not initialized.

Comment: There is a difference between defining a variable and saving/restoring a variable. You defined variables v1 and v2. You saved a value of v2 and you also saved the whole graph (i.e. all created variable definitions). If you then load the saved graph, all variables defined before will be present in the graph. But that does not mean their values will be restored. In your case only v2 will be restored and v1 will remain uninitialized.

Comment: The problem is that the Saver saves and restores both the variables (and takes memory for both?), despite I passed a subset of variables for it to store.

Comment: OK, I got it. Do you mean that v1 doesn't take memory upon restoring?

Comment: I don't know how it is done in tensorflow but I guess it is likely it takes memory. But the memory is uninitialized. If you want to restore only v2 then only create the v2 variable like you did the first time by tf.get_variable and then just call tf.train.Saver([v2]).restore(..) or in case you want to restore all variables you defined (now only v2) you do not need to pass [v2] argument. Saver.restore restores only already defined variables so it cannot restore v1 if v1 is not in the graph.

Comment: "The problem is that the Saver saves and restores both the variables"... No, by calling restore, saver restores only values of v2. Try restoring v1 and it will fail because saver does not have value of the v1. By default saver aside from the variable values saves the definition of the current graph. If you load the saved graph, you load all variable definitions but not their values. But it is different from restoring variable values by restore call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176170/discussion-between-kurtosis-and-user2781994).